# Access to files via URI Android 11

Tags: uri, mediastore, android-11, android-fileprovider, android-storage

In my project I am using external native library (no source code). One of the library functions receives the URI parameter as input.

On older devices (earlier than android 11) everything works correctly. For instance:

```
inputUri = Uri.parse("file:///" + inputFileNameConvert); // file:////storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/cache/temp/record.mp3
```

But for android 11+, due to the [restrictions imposed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage), I use FileProvider.

```
 inputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, new File(inputFileNameConvert)); // content://packagename/cache/temp/record.mp3
```

The `content` schema does not work correctly in the native library. I get an error:

> The uri source has an incorrect format or an unsupported scheme

How can i pass uri to function with schema `file`? I need to create a file anywhere on the device without getting permission `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify what type of file are you trying to get? Are yo trying to get folder access or just a media file?

Comment: @Dev4Life In my application, I record voice in mp4a format. After this file I use via uri as an argument to the library function. So you are right. This specific file format

Comment: Can you tell me what different methods have you tried?

Comment: @Dev4Life two variants: 1) content://packagename/cache/temp/record.mp3 - bad uri type error 2) file:////storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/cache/temp/record.mp3 - access error